# pulling information from nested dictionaries: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, tkinter, encryption

> I put some information into a file which is read out and put into a nested dictionary and Signup works fine until you want to login as it says:

```
second = account[user]["second"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

> This happens when I want to call back the time from the users dictionary but everything else works.
> Sorry for a mess but I'm too puzzled to why it is doing this.
> Please help
> Sorry for any inconvenience

```
import os
from itertools import islice
import sys
import time
import random as r
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
from tkinter import messagebox as error
import re
import tkinter as tk

s=0
account= []
accounts = {}
a=0
alphabet = "1234567890@.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!$%^&*()_+-=/*:;~#?>,<|\{}[]"""
letter_to_index = dict(zip(alphabet, range(len(alphabet))))
index_to_letter = dict(zip(range(len(alphabet)), alphabet))
regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'

##Creates a new file for the database if it isnt found and goes to loginpopup
def filecreator():
   f=open('accounts_project.txt', "w")
   f.close()
   loginpopup()

##Error is found here. this is meant to get the time (when account was created)from the nested 
##dictionary and encrypt the password the same for comparing but it comes up: TypeError: list indices 
##must be integers or slices, not str
def loginencrypt(user, passwd):
   global accounts 
   hour = accounts[user]["hour"] 
   minute = accounts[user]["minute"]
   second = account[user]["seconds"]
   encrypted = ""
   split_message = [
       passwd[i : i + len(user)] for i in range(0, len(passwd), len(user))
   ]
   for each_split in split_message:
       i = 0
       for letter in each_split:
           number = (letter_to_index[letter] - hour + letter_to_index[user[i]] +  minute - second - i) % len(alphabet)
           encrypted += index_to_letter[number]
           i += 1
   return encrypted    

##this sends data to loginencrypt to encrypt the password but also it compares data and will handle 
   emailing to account owners when it is implemented    
def find_login(user, passwd):
   global s
   global accounts
   userexist = accounts.get(user)
   if userexist:
       encrypt = loginencrypt(user, passwd)
       if accounts[user]["password"] == encrypt:
           print("Welcome to your account")
       else:
           error.showerror("Invalid Password","Wrong Password")
           if s == 5:
               error.showerror("Run","The real user of this account was contacted")
               if accounts[user]["email"] == "no":
                    reset()
               else:
                   print("no")
           else:
               s+=1       
   else:
       error.showerror("Invalid account","Please Signup Instead")

##this encrypts the password to be stored inside of the database        
def encrypt(passwd, user, hour, minute, second):
    encrypted = ""
    split_message = [
        passwd[i : i + len(user)] for i in range(0, len(passwd), len(user))
    ]
    for each_split in split_message:
        i = 0
        for letter in each_split:
            number = (letter_to_index[letter] - hour + letter_to_index[user[i]] +  minute - second - i) % len(alphabet)
            encrypted += index_to_letter[number]
            i += 1
    return encrypted

##this opens the file and gets all the data from it (seperated by |)in the form of a nested 
##dictionary.
def filereader():
   global accounts
   with open("accounts_project.txt", 'r') as f:
       for line in f:
           listDetails = line.strip().split('|')
           usernames = listDetails[0]
           accounts[usernames] = {"username": listDetails[0]}
           accounts[usernames].update({"password": listDetails[1]})
           accounts[usernames].update({"email": listDetails[2]})
           accounts[usernames].update({"hour": listDetails[3]})
           accounts[usernames].update({"minute": listDetails[4]})
           accounts[usernames].update({"seconds": listDetails[5]})
loginpopup()

##this gets all the data made by signing up the account and seperates it with a | and saves it inside 
##the file
def filesaver(account, login):
   global accounts
   save = ("|".join(account)+"\n")
   f=open('accounts_project.txt', "a")
   f.write(save)
   f.close()
   del account[0:6]
   if login ==1:
       print("hi")
   else:
       reset()

##this checks if a username is entered     
def login(username, password):
   user = username.get()
   passwd = password.get()
   if len(user)==0:
       error.showerror("error","Please enter a username")
   else:
       find_login(user, passwd)

##this resets the login window as 5 tries were attempted to break in         
def resetlogin():
   global s
   global tkWindow
   s = 0
   tkWindow.destroy()
   filereader()

##this does the same but after signing up so only the login window is visible      
def reset():
   global tkWindow
   global signupas
   signupas.destroy()
   tkWindow.destroy()
   filereader()

##not implemented yet but it is meant to send the email to the user for verification
def checkuser_email(account, emails):
   global signupas
   global accountS
   print(emails)

##this checks if the user exists, username is entered and password for registration, checks if email 
##is entered when 2step is on.
##It might be on about the bottom bit of it but it worked fine there but I cant call it now.
def popup(username,password,var1, email, var2):
   global accounts
   global account
   checklist= var1.get()
   user = username.get()
   passwd = password.get()
   emails = email.get() 
   login = var2.get()
   if len(user) == 0:
       error.showerror("Invalid username","Please enter a username")
   elif len(user)>0:
           if len(passwd) < 7:
              error.showerror("error","Password isn't 7 characters long")
           else:
               userexists = accounts.get(user)
               if userexists:
                   error.showerror("username exists","Username already exists\n please login instead")
               else:
                   if checklist == 1:
                       if len(emails)==0:
                           error.showerror("error","Enter email")
                       elif len(emails)>0:
                           if not re.match(r"^[A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]*$", emails):  
                               error.showerror("Invalid email","Please enter a valid email")
                           else:
                               account.append(user)
                               account.append(passwd)
                               checkuser_email(account, emails)
                   else:
                       ##put Yes here
                       if error.askyesno("Are you sure?", "Are you sure? \nIt will be harder to retrieve your account.\n You can always add it later", icon='error')==True:           
                           ##could be on about this here?
                          ##anyone know a better way of doing the same?           
                           account.append(user)
                           emaila = "no"
                           t= time.localtime()
                           account.append(emaila)
                           hour = time.strftime("%H")
                           hour = int(hour)
                           minute = time.strftime("%M")
                           minute = int(minute)
                           second = time.strftime("%S")
                           second = int(second)
                           encrypted_pass = encrypt(passwd, user, hour, minute, second)
                           account.insert(1, encrypted_pass)
                           hour= str(hour)
                           minute= str(minute)
                           second = str(second)
                           account.append(hour)
                           account.append(minute)
                           account.append(second)
                           filesaver(account, login)

##this is the signup pop up. Dont tick anything and for he popup press yes.                                
def signup():
   global signupas
   signupas = tk.Toplevel()
   signupas.geometry('400x200')  
   signupas.title("Sign Up")
   usernameLabel = Label(signupas, text="Username")
   usernameLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
   username = StringVar()
   usernameEntry = Entry(signupas, textvariable=username)
   usernameEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)  
   passwordLabel = Label(signupas,text="Password")
   passwordLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)  
   password = StringVar()
   passwordEntry = Entry(signupas, textvariable=password, show='*')
   passwordEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
   var1 = IntVar()
   Checkbutton(signupas, text="2step verification", variable=var1).grid(row=2, column=0)
   var2 = IntVar()
   Checkbutton(signupas, text="Login after?", variable=var2).grid(row=2, column=1)    
   emailLabel = Label(signupas, text="Email")
   emailLabel.grid(row=3, column=0)
   email = StringVar()
   emailEntry = Entry(signupas, textvariable=email)
   emailEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)
   SignUp = partial(popup, username, password, var1, email, var2)
   signupButton = Button(signupas, text="SignUp", command=SignUp).grid(row=5, column=0)
   noteLabel = Label(signupas, text="For 2step verification tick box,\n type your email and Signup").grid(row=6, column=1)
   signupas.mainloop()

##this checks if file is empty: locks the login button so signup is only possible                                                        
def loginpopup():
   global tkWindow
   tkWindow = Tk() 
   global accounts
   print(accounts)
   tkWindow.geometry('400x150')  
   tkWindow.title("Database Program")
   usernameLabel = Label(tkWindow, text="Username").grid(row=0, column=0)
   username = StringVar()
   usernameEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=username).grid(row=0, column=1)  
   passwordLabel = Label(tkWindow,text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)  
   password = StringVar()
   passwordEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=password, show='*').grid(row=1, column=1)
   Login = partial(login, username, password)
   SignUp = partial(signup)
   loginButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Login", command=Login)
   loginButton.grid(row=4, column=0)
   signupButton = Button(tkWindow, text="SignUp", command=SignUp).grid(row=4, column=1)
   if os.path.getsize('accounts_project.txt') ==0:
       loginButton['state'] = DISABLED
   else:
       loginButton['state'] = NORMAL
       pass
   tkWindow.mainloop()

##this controls what to do and if the file exists       
file = os.path.exists('accounts_project.txt')
if file == True:
   filereader()
else:
   filecreator()
```

Comment: Sorry for the length of it but its better to show  all of it instead of a segment.

Comment: ```account= []```. ```account``` is a list, not a dictionary? The error is telling you that you cannot index a list like a dictionary.

Comment: damn yes mixed up the dictionary with the list. Dictionary is called accounts while list is called account. Thanks

Comment: u can suffix it like `list_account` and `dict_accounts` so u wont get confused on a future occurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `second = account[user]["seconds"]`
to `second = accounts[user]["seconds"]`